# How do I compute a PMF and CDF for a binomial distribution in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, probability

I need to calculate the probability mass function, and cumulative distribution function, of the [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). I would like to use MATLAB to do this (raw MATLAB, no toolboxes). I can calculate these myself, but was hoping to use a predefined function and can't find any. Is there something out there?

```
function x = homebrew_binomial_pmf(N,p)
    x = [1];
    for i = 1:N
       x = [0 x]*p + [x 0]*(1-p);
    end
```

Comment: Too bad you don't want to use the Statistics Toolbox... it's got the functions BINOPDF and BINOCDF. ;)

Comment: I'll use the toolboxes we have, when Mathworks fixes their draconian licensing policy, that makes floating network licenses 4x as expensive as fixed, and doesn't return network licenses to the pool until you close MATLAB, and doesn't offer a mechanism to manually return network licenses to the pool. Sorry for the rant, but you hit a nerve here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [NCHOOSEK](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/nchoosek.html) to compute the binomial coefficient. With that, you can create a function that computes the value of the probability mass function for a set of `k` values for a given `N` and `p`:

```
function pmf = binom_dist(N,p,k)
  nValues = numel(k);
  pmf = zeros(1,nValues);
  for i = 1:nValues
    pmf(i) = nchoosek(N,k(i))*p^k(i)*(1-p)^(N-k(i));
  end
end
```

To plot the probability mass function, you would do the following:

```
k = 0:40;
pmf = binom_dist(40,0.5,k);
plot(k,pmf,'r.');
```

and the cumulative distribution function can be found from the probability mass function using [CUMSUM](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/cumsum.html):

```
cummDist = cumsum(pmf);
plot(k,cummDist,'r.');
```

---

**NOTE:** When the binomial coefficient returned from [NCHOOSEK](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/nchoosek.html) is large you can end up losing precision. A very nice alternative is to use the submission [Variable Precision Integer Arithmetic](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22725-variable-precision-integer-arithmetic) from [John D'Errico](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/679) on the [MathWorks File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/). By converting your numbers to his `vpi` type, you can avoid the precision loss.

Comment: @Jason: Very true. Just in case it ends up being a problem for you, I added some links to a MathWorks submission by John D'Errico which allows you to perform variable precision integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

looks like for the [CDF of the binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function), my best bet is the [incomplete beta function betainc](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/betainc.html).

Answer (score 1):

octave provides a good collection of distribution pdf, cdf, quantile; they have to be translated from octave, but this is relatively trivial (convert `endif` to `end`, convert `!=` to `~=`, etc;) see e.g. [octave binocdf](http://velveeta.che.wisc.edu/cgi-bin/hgwebdir.cgi/octave/file/tip//scripts/statistics/distributions/binocdf.m?rev=HEAD&content-type=text/plain) for the binomial cdf function.

Answer (score -1):

For PDF

```
x=1:15
p=.45

c=binopdf(x,15,p)

plot(x,c)
```

Similarly CDF

```
D=binocdf(x,15,p) 

plot(x,D)
```

Comment: However, OP requested "raw MATLAB, no toolboxes"; `binopdf`and `binocdf` are part of the statistics toolbox.